# Why does return literals in the handler create `TypeError: Expected a semicolon`?

Tags: javascript, deno, preact, automatic-semicolon-insertion, freshjs

Here is my workable `index.tsx` route:

```js
import { Handlers, PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";

export const handler: Handlers<Data> = {
  GET(req, ctx) {
    const a = 'hello'
    return ctx.render({ a })
  },
};

export default function Home({ data }: PageProps<Data>) {
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(data) } 
    </>
  );
}
```

However if I change the handler from:

```js
const a = 'hello'
return ctx.render({ a })
```

to:

```js
return ctx.render({ 'hello' })
```

I get this error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Expected a semicolon at file:///D:/QC%20supplements/Code/Apps/trankyweb/routes/index.tsx:24:33

      return ctx.render({ 'hello' })
                                  ~
  const manifest = (await import(toFileUrl(join(dir, "fresh.gen.ts")).href))
                    ^
    at async dev (https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.6.1/src/dev/dev_command.ts:38:21)
    at async file:///D:/QC%20supplements/Code/Apps/trankyweb/dev.ts:5:1
Watcher Process failed. Restarting on file change...
```

What does this mean? I read [SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement) but I don't see how it's applying to this.

The `fresh.gen.ts` file is automatically generated. Here is the content of `dev.ts`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/

import dev from "$fresh/dev.ts";

await dev(import.meta.url, "./main.ts");
```

Comment: can yo add the code, say 3 or 4 lines, before and after the line with the error `const manifest = ...` - not sure why you posted the code you posted since that has nothing to do with the actual error - and why are you putting `()` around the await anyway? shouldn't it be `const manifest = await import(toFileUrl(join(dir, "fresh.gen.ts")).href)` - though, showing more code will help (I can guess why you would do it that way)

Comment: The `fresh.gen.ts` file is automatically generated, so I don't know about it. I've added the content of `dev.ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because ctx.render() expects object: {a} is equivalent to {a: value of a}. This is not jsx templating that u think u are using, this is function call that expects object. By providing string literal  we cant know which is the key and which is the value, it would be invalid es6 shorthand syntax for object initialization.

```
a='asd'
const obj = {a}
```

obj is {a: 'asd'}

providint only string literal in initializer however is invalid es6 shorthand sybtax. Because ctx.render is function call it does not expect jsx templating syntax, but object

Comment: I try this and the error still happens

Comment: return ctx.render({ 'hello' }) - could it be related because you are putting string literal instead of variable, as thet are different things

Comment: why do variables works but literals don't?

Comment: because ctx.render() expects object:     {a} is equivalent to {a: <value of a>}. This is not jsx templating that u think u are using, this is function call that expects object. By providing string literal u actually provide object {undefined:'literal}

Comment: I see. If you add this to the answer I'll accept it. Also, what is this syntax called?

Comment: u are trying to create object with literal only provided, which is invalid syntax because it doesnt know what is the key and what is the value of the object. If it is variable then object can be created with variable as key and its value as value, but that doesnt work for literals

Comment: u can find it as.ES6 Object property shorthand